# How to stop one song and start another in android?

Tags: android

I'm using two activities, first activity displays all the mp3 songs in my phone in a listview and second activity is used to show the playing song name and a seekbar. But if a song is playing and i come back first activity and select another song in the listview both the songs play without stopping first song. I used mediaplayer.stop, mediaplayer.reset and still its not working

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: all the code? code of 2 activities?

Comment: Well it would be sufficient to only see the parts where you use the mediaplayer.

Comment: i used this to check whether mediaplayer is already playing a song or not   if (mp != null){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. It should solve your issue.

Comment: The problem is how to check whether  mediplayer is already playing something and if its playing something how to stop it and play another song(which will be chosen in first activity's listview). Just tell me how to check and stop mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you used more than a single Mediaplayer object.

Make sure that you use the same object within all activities, you might want to save it in your application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.far);
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }

}
```

Then use it in your activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getMediaPlayer().start();
         // ...
     }
}
```

Do not forget to register your application class in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="com.your.package.MyApplication">
```